# WPF Button use different icon for enabled and disabled state

Tags: wpf, button

How can I give my button different icons depending on the Enabled state. Not very familiar with Style setters yet.

XAML button:

```
        <Button 
            x:Name="DownloadNewestEpisodes" 
            Width="90" 
            Margin="5,5"
            ToolTip="Download newest episodes"
            ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
            Command="w:MainWindow.DownloadNewestEpisodesCommand"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TvShowsTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">

            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="../icons/import.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

How can I switch between

```
<Image Source="../icons/import.png" />
```

and

```
<Image Source="../icons/import_disabled.png" />
```

based on the enabled state of the button?

A little help would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DataTrigger`:

```
<Button...
    >
    <StackPanel>
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="..." />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="..." />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: would you know why this rotates the image 180 degrees?

Comment: nevermind figured it out, problem was in the parent stackpanel. it defined right to left flow, which was inherited by my image (and thus became mirrored). +1 and accepted as this one solved my original problem. thx again!

Answer (score 2):

Set *default image in setter* and use *DataTrigger to switch to other value* (in case IsEnabled set to False):

```
<Button>
   <Image>
      <Image.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/a.png"/>
              <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                          AncestorType=Button}}"
                              Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/c.png"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </Image.Style>
  </Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, had to go for the other answer this time, can't get this to work. I would favor this answer though, it saves me one data trigger definition

Comment: Are you sure bas because i posted this after trying in small sample and it works for me. Two triggers definitely not needed, in case first trigger doesn't satisfy condition it will roll back to default value. Make sure you are setting default value using Style setter only and not locally on image.

Comment: For what it's worth this one worked for me.  Actually they both worked.